# How to add extra class to div using DRI Pre-Processing

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

I would like to add extra class to the Comment section in the Feedback form. Using Mirage 2 theme, the HTML looked like this:

```
<div class="control-group col-sm-12">
    <label for="aspect_artifactbrowser_FeedbackForm_field_comments" class="control-label">Comments:&nbsp;</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" onkeydown="event.cancelBubble=true;" onfocus="javascript:tFocus(this);" name="comments" class="ds-textarea-field form-control" id="aspect_artifactbrowser_FeedbackForm_field_comments"> </textarea>
</div>
```

I want to add an extra class eg `<div class="myClass control-group col-sm-12">`

In `preprocess.xsl`, I have this code:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:field[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.FeedbackForm.field.comments' and @n='comments' and @type='textarea']" priority="3">
    <div class="myClass">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

But the above code returns this HTML below:

```
<div class="control-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="ds-static-div">Comments</div>
</div>
```

which is just displaying the word **Comments**

What is wrong with my `xsl:template match`?

Answer (score 1):

The preprocess step is a DRI to DRI transformation, not a DRI to HTML transformation.
If you want to capture a `dri:field` and just add an attribute to it, do it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:field[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.FeedbackForm.field.comments' and @n='comments' and @type='textarea']" priority="3">
    <field>
        <xsl:call-template name="copy-attributes"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="rend">
            <xsl:value-of select="@rend" />
            <xsl:text> myClass</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </field>
</xsl:template>
```

`rend` is usually the attribute that gets mapped to `class` by the theme. But you may want to look up exactly which template in the theme will be applied to that specific `dri:field`.

Comment: I tried this and it adds a class in the textarea, but I want the additional class in its parent container, ie in `<div class="control-group col-sm-12">` How can I target that? Looking at its DRI, the parent of `dri:field[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.FeedbackForm.field.comments and @n='comments' and @type='textarea']` is just `<item>`